# What is this annoying point in the guideline, and how to remove its label?

Tags: inkscape, guides

I noted that every guideline has an *annoying point* on it, which may be dragged along it, but I don't see any way how to *remove it*.

I noted, too, that guidelines in some templates have *labels*, and again, I'm not able *to remove them* – guidelines are not objects, their labels are not text objects, context menu (right-click) on a guideline is helpless.

[image]

So my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of this annoying point other than moving the label with it?
2. How may I get rid of the guideline's label - or how may I create it?

Comment: The guide anchor is useful if you want to align something to it, using snapping for example.  I use this feature frequently.  You can't remove the guide anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. That annoying point is an **anchor point**, and it is useful in 2 ways:

   - It serves as an *extra magnet* (beside the whole magnetic guideline - if you have set snapping to guide lines).
   - You may rotate the guideline around it – just hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down and drag the guideline with the mouse.

   [image: Rotating guideline]
2. Double-click the guideline and use the popped-up dialog box to add / remove a label:

   [image]

---

*Note:*

If you need guidelines slanted in 45<sup>o</sup> angle, you may simply drag them from the very ends of rulers:

[image]